# How can I force a build process to fail through a Unity editor script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to force the build process to fail if some validation conditions are not met.

I've tried using an `IPreprocessBuildWithReport` with no success:

```cs
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;

public class BuildProcessor : IPreprocessBuildWithReport
{
    public int callbackOrder => 0;

    public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildReport report)
    {
        // Attempt 1
        // Does not compile because the 'BuildSummary.result' is read only
        report.summary.result = BuildResult.Failed;

        // Attempt 2
        // Causes a log in the Unity editor, but the build still succeeds
        throw new BuildFailedException("Forced fail");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to programmatically force the build process to fail?

I'm using Unity 2018.3.8f1.

Comment: Did you get it to work somehow?

Comment: @derHugo unfortunately no. It would fail on some platforms and not on others, and in some it would even fail just some times. The best I could do for a consistent behaviour was to just log an error and if it was an automated build I force quit the Unity editor application, thus forcing the build to fail. On a normal (user operated) usage, it just logs the error which hopefully is visible enough for the user to understand that it should have failed even though it proceeded with the build.

Comment: Thanks for the update .. its a pity .. trying to do the same but I do not want to await the entire build just for realizing it actually should have failed ^^

Answer (score 8):

As of 2019.2.14f1, the correct way to stop the build is to throw a `BuildFailedException`.
Other exception types **do not** interrupt the build.
Derived exception types **do not** interrupt the build.
Logging errors most certainly **do not** interrupt the build.

This is how Unity handles exceptions in [PostProcessPlayer](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/2dce98888bf4f3b50cdb55b3ee761414b15bf7dc/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs):

```cs
try
{
    postprocessor.PostProcess(args, out props);
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    // Rethrow exceptions during build postprocessing as BuildFailedException, so we don't pretend the build was fine.
    throw new UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException(e);
}
```

Just for clarity, this will **NOT** stop the build.:

```cs
// This is not precisely a BuildFailedException. So the build will go on and succeed.
throw new CustomBuildFailedException();

...

public class CustomBuildFailedException: BuildException() {}
```

Comment: The question already shows that in the asker's scenario, throwing a `BuildFailedException` does not cause the build to fail.

Comment: I was probably not clear. Yes, in Unity 2018.3.8f1 it does not work, which seems to be a bug. However, in 2019.2.14f1 it works perfectly well.

Comment: It may be a bug, but this answer does not help with the question, as that is the version the asker is using.

Comment: This seems to work for me on 2021.3.13f1.

Comment: I am currently trying to throw a BuildFailedException in BuildPlayerProcessor.PrepareForBuild (Unity 2021.3.21f1) and it results in Unity coming down as a whole with an error "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way."

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnValidate() which seems to be exactly what you're looking for. 
Let's say you want to make sure a reference to a UI Text component is not null before building, in the script that should have the text reference, you add

```
private void OnValidate()
{
     if (text == null)
     {
          Debug.LogError("Text reference is null!");
     }
}
```

Having Debug.LogError calls during the build process actually cause the build to fail.

Comment: I never even heard of that function. Did you just do a rapid search through the docs to find that, or are you familiar with using it?

Comment: I've used it before! I use it to validate stuff inside Unity. The example case I gave you is a real case I met before. My OnValidate looked like
`private void OnValidate()
{
     if (!text)
     {
           text = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
     }

     if (!text)
     {
          Debug.LogError("No TMPro component assigned!");
     }
}`

When I was building, it didn't build because of that debug.logerror message! I was lucky to find it and now use it a lot.

Comment: That doesn't work for me for 2 reasons: 1 - Are you using Unity 2018.3? I've tried it but that does not fail the build at all for me (it does print the exception, but the build succeeds)... Or maybe you are making a build with strict mode enabled? 2 - The validate only runs for MonoBehaviours (and ScriptableObjects, despite not being documented) so that means the script needs to be associated with an asset. I wish to have it on some editor callback instead. That does not seem to work

Comment: It's weird that it doesn't work for you! You could try throwing an exception instead, that must work! Also, sorry about the late response.